# Including files in Maven gwt:test

Tags: gwt, maven

When you issue 'mvn gwt:test', Maven creates a target/www-test -directory. This dir contains the actual tests being ran under another directory based on you package, e.g. target/www-test/com.mydomain.test.SomeApp.JUnit

I need to include a javascript file to this directory, or my tests will fail. How do I do this ? The documentation doesn't seem to provide an option to include files here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subfolder name is actually based upon the module name your `GWTTestCase` returns from `getModuleName()`, with a `JUnit` suffix (GWT generates on-the-fly a module that inherits your module and the `com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit` module, among other things).

So, if you need some specific things for your test, you can very well create a test-specific module that inherits your "standard" module, and return that new module from `getModuleName` (GWT unit tests do that for testing some `set-property` or `set-configuration-property` values, or declare `servlet`s for testing GWT-RPC, RequestFactory or `FormPanel`, for instance).

Now, if you only need a JS file, you can put it in your *public path* (i.e. by default, a `public` folder next to your `gwt.xml` module descriptor file). And you can use `<script>` in your `gwt.xml` to automatically pull that script inside the test page (because tests use a *standard* `junit.html` or `junit-standard.html` web page). If you really need to, you can override that HTML page by putting one with the same name in your *public path*, it should then override the one from the `com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit` module (you might have to explicitly inherit that module though, so its *public path* comes before yours)

See also:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModules
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ResourceOracle

Comment: Creating the public folder and putting the JS file there worked like a charm, thanks :)

Hope stuff like this was properly documented.

Comment: Er, well, it is: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModules The rest is about how you use it (e.g. take advantage of the fact you have different classpaths for compilation and running tests). Overriding the `junit.html` pages is a hack that should only be used as a last resort though.

Comment: Heh, so *there* it was, I was looking through docs in Maven and GWT Testing ... Would've been nice if it was also mentioned there.